# Reading from CSV produces duplicate entries in variable

Tags: csv, powershell

I have this bit of code :

```
$servers = Import-Csv "sources.csv"
$computername = $servers.server
$ServiceName = $servers.services
```

`sources.csv` contains the following..

```
Server,Services
BRWS40,winrm
BRWS84,winrm
```

I have then a `foreach`, and the `Write-Host` is within that, it output this:

```
Write-Host "$computername - $ServiceName" -ForegroundColor black -BackgroundColor red
```

Output from above I get is:

```
BRWS40 BRWS84 - winrm winrm
```

Whereas I was wanting to have one computer and service per line.

```
BRWS40 - winrm
```

What am I doing wrong?

I amended the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926333/how-to-retrieve-data-from-excel-for-ip-ping/34926730#34926730).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have to loop through your result:

```
$servers = Import-Csv "sources.csv"

$servers | %{
    $computername = $_.server
    $ServiceName = $_.services

    write-host "$computername - $ServiceName" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor red
}
```

or use the Format-Table cmdlet:

```
$servers | Format-Table
```

Comment: Thanks for both of your answers, i can now amend that and finish my script.

I have seen the $_.server used before, but just didnt understand how it was used. i now have a better understanding of it. 

I am in the process of making a script that will run and check various services on different computers. 

by using borrowed code from a few sites, this site is really a great help. 

Thanks again, it really is appreciated. .

Answer (score 2):

`$servers = Import-Csv "sources.csv"` imports the content of `sources.csv` as a list of custom objects into the variable `$servers`.

`$computername = $servers.server` selects the value of the `server` property of each object into the variable `$computername`, thus generating a list of computer names.

`$ServiceName = $servers.services` selects the value of the `services` property of each object into the variable `$ServiceName`, thus generating a list of service names.

Note that `$array.property` will only work in PowerShell v3 and newer, because earlier versions don't automatically unroll the array to get the element properties, but try to access the property of the array object itself. If the array doesn't have such a property, the result will be `$null`, otherwise it will be the value of the property of the array. Either way it won't be what you want. To make the property expansion work across all PowerShell versions use `Select-Object -Expand` or echo the property in a `ForEach-Object` statement:

```
$computername = $servers | Select-Object -Expand server
$computername = $servers | ForEach-Object { $_.server }
```

When you put array variables in a string (`"$computername - $ServiceName"`) the array elements are joined by the [`$OFS`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) character (space by default), so `"$computername"` becomes `BRWS40 BRWS84` and `"$ServiceName"` becomes `winrm winrm`.

To get the corresponding service name for each computer you need to process `$servers` in a loop, for instance:

```
foreach ($server in $servers) {
  Write-Host ('{0} - {1}' -f $server.Server, $server.Services) ...
}
```

If you don't need a specific output format you could also use one of the [`Format-*`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347677.aspx) cmdlets, for instance [`Format-Table`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849892.aspx):

```
Import-Csv "sources.csv" | Format-Table -AutoSize
```